# SlickSlider высот через padding-bottom

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Возникла необходимость встроить слайдер в уже имеющийся сайт. Высота задаётся с помощью padding-bottom, но вот при использовании slickslider итог получается такой, что картинка всего в высоту 1 px и то, эта высота имеется благодаря этому, как я понимаю, стилю в slick.css

```
        .slick-slide
    {
        display: none;
        float: left;
    
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
    }
```

У меня имеется простая структура

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="box pr slider single-item">
         <div><img src="images/img1.jpg"  class="img br10"></div>
         <div><img src="images/img2.jpg"  class="img sss br10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Высота картинки задаётся так:

```
.img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.box{
    padding-bottom: 70%;
    height: 0;
}
```

Ранее со слайдерами не работал вообще, по этому даже не совсем понимаю куда смотреть. Может кто подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы при задании высоты именно через padding-bottom работал слайдер корректно?